# How to not alter the information between variable type?

Tags: java, string, byte

I would like to replace fixed values by variables in this line:

`baData = new byte[] {(byte)0xec, (byte)0xee};`

(byte)0xec and (byte)0xee are the values to replace with a variable.

Now, the variables I have are currently strings like:
    str1="ec"; and str2="ee";

How do I properly convert these strings to byte and tell Java no to alter the information? I want for example that baData takes ec and ee as hex value, but so far I could not find anything working.

And once this is done, how do I re-write the first line to put the variables instead of fixed values?

Comment: `str1.getBytes()`?

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak: No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically if you have a string containing hex, and you want to parse it as a byte, you can use [`Byte.parseByte`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte(str1, 16);
```

However, your values `ec` and `ee` are outside the allowed range for Java signed bytes (`-128` to `+127`), so this will give you a number format exception.

To get around this, you can parse it as an int and then cast it to a byte

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt("ec", 16);
```

This will give you a byte value of `-20` (signed decimal), or `236` (unsigned decimal), which is `0xec` in hex.

For your purposes, you could use:

```
baData = new byte[] {
    (byte) Integer.parseInt(str1, 16),
    (byte) Integer.parseInt(str2, 16),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That's the answer I have been looking for. I just tested it and it works just fine.
Many thanks!